# Classification issues with Binary Sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to conduct a binary sentiment analysis of Arabic text (i.e. either classifying social media posts into negative/positive). I built a basic dictionary that covers all words included in the social media posts in my dataset.

However, after running the code below to classify posts, all ended up being classified as neutral statements, although some posts strictly included negative words. So I decided to classify text as negative or positive phrases, and it is still showing all text as neutral as below, although again some posts only contain negative words.

```
post
<chr>
label
<chr>
يافرحه ماتمت           neutral          
ارفعو خطاب لوزارة      neutral          
كل شي مكتوب            neutral          
تفائلوا بالخير تجدوهـ  neutral
```

Here is a data sample from the posts and dictionary:

```
positive_phrases          negative_phrases
تفائلوا بالخير تجدوهـ     يافرحه ماتمت  
كل شي مكتوب                  ارفعو خطاب لوزارة
```

Here is my current code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#install.packages("stringr")
#install.packages("readxl")
```

Importing dictionary dataset:

```
> Dictionary <- read_excel("Documents/Sentiment_posts/Dictionary.xlsx")
```

```
test %>% mutate(p_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$positive, collapse = '|')), 
                 n_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$negative, collapse = '|'))) %>% 
           mutate(label = case_when(p_count > n_count ~ 'positive',
                                    p_count > n_count ~ 'positive_phrases',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative_phrases',
                                    TRUE ~ 'neutral')) %>% select(post, label)
```

When I ran the same code, but an English translated version of posts, the classification worked well, which is why I believe there is an issue with R recognizing/reading the Arabic text.

```
test %>% mutate(p_count = str_count(english_post, str_c(Testing_dictionary$positive, collapse = '|')), 
                 n_count = str_count(english_post, str_c(Testing_dictionary$negative, collapse = '|'))) %>% 
           mutate(label = case_when(p_count > n_count ~ 'positive',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative',
                                    TRUE ~ 'neutral')) %>% select(post, label)
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with tidyverse so I could be wrong but your `case_when` seems strange to me, in particular the last line `TRUE ~ 'neutral'`. Maybe try to replace this condition with `p_count == n_count`. Also it's strange that you have twice the same condition with different labels.

Comment: Thanks, check the updated question. It's not really the same condition as one captures negative words, while another captures a negative/positive phrase (i.e. group of words).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the syntax with tidyverse, but I don't see how two identical conditions can give different outcomes. Anyway about your main question you should certainly investigate what happens: take a few cases which look like errors, apply your counting of positive/negative words, check manually if the results are correct. You should try to first find whether the problem comes from the data or from the code, and second if it comes from the code it means that there's a bug to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I have checked both causes and I actually believe that the issue comes from how R is reading Arabic text data in the Excel file. This is because when I used the same code with an English translated dataset of the original Arabic text, most posts were correctly classified as what I would expect. I have added a code on how I have been importing the datasets if that helps.

Comment: I don't know much about this in R. But if it's a problem related to charset encoding or something similar it should be easier to solve, you could ask a question on https://stackoverflow.com/ about this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwan!
Apart from any issues in the encoding, do you recommend ant adjustments to the code?

Comment: Not really, I don't know much about these libraries to be honest.